# T2UH Wlan Adapter Problems

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox, compiling, make

i am struggling by installing the TP-Link AC600 Archer T2UH on my VirtualBox. I wasted hours to get it work yet but i didnt get it yet. So i decided to ask the community to help me.

First of all i am running: `Ubuntu 16.10 Linux version 4.8.0-22-generic (buildd@lgw01-11) (gcc version 6.2.0 20161005 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) ) #24-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 8 09:15:00 UTC 2016` in a Virtualbox Version 5.18

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp
```

So, but thats the only thing i get out of this Adapter. There is a Problem to bind it into the Virtualbox. As I am trying to select it from my USB List (it is called **RALINK Technology Corp. 0100**) there is a failuremessage incoming USB Device 'RalinkTechnologyCorp.' with UUID ... is busy with a previous request. Please try again later.
The thing is, that i also deactivated the Hostdrivers of the Stick, so in my opinion it cant be requested by the Hostsystem.
Perhaps this failure is justified by not installing the Driver?

The other problem I got is the Driverinstallation. I followed the Instructions of the following link:
https://www.myria.de/computer/1308-tp-link-archer-t2u-ac600-unter-linux-nutzen

But anytime i tried to compile the driver for my device, following Failuremessage is coming out of the terminal:

```
make -C tools
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools“ wird betreten
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools“ wird verlassen
/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools/bin2h
chipset = mt7610u
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-22-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic“ wird betreten
  CC [M]  /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o
In file included from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_os.h:44:0,
                 from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
                 from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rt_config.h:33,
                 from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:28:
/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/os/rt_linux.h:77:0: warning: "EXT_BUILD_CHANNEL_LIST" redefined
 #define EXT_BUILD_CHANNEL_LIST  /* must define with CRDA */

<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/os/rt_linux.h:98:0,
                 from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_os.h:44,
                 from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
                 from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rt_config.h:33,
                 from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:28:
/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/cfg80211.h:35:49: error: ‘IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  struct ieee80211_supported_band Cfg80211_bands[IEEE80211_NUM_BANDS];
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c: In function ‘announce_802_3_packet’:
/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:341:16: warning: unused variable ‘pAd’ [-Wunused-variable]
  RTMP_ADAPTER *pAd = (RTMP_ADAPTER *)pAdSrc;
                ^~~
In file included from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_os.h:44:0,
                 from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rtmp_comm.h:75,
                 from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/rt_config.h:33,
                 from /home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:28:
/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c: In function ‘STA_MonPktSend’:
/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:450:35: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
         DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s : Size is too large! (%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, pRxBlk->DataSize + sizeof(wlan_ng_prism2_header)));
                                   ^
/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/include/os/rt_linux.h:669:16: note: in definition of macro ‘DBGPRINT_RAW’
         printk Fmt;               \
                ^~~
/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:450:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘DBGPRINT’
         DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s : Size is too large! (%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, pRxBlk->DataSize + sizeof(wlan_ng_prism2_header)));
         ^~~~~~~~
scripts/Makefile.build:289: die Regel für Ziel „/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o“ scheiterte
make[2]: *** [/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o] Fehler 1
Makefile:1489: die Regel für Ziel „_module_/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux“ scheiterte
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/nico/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic“ wird verlassen
Makefile:403: die Regel für Ziel „LINUX“ scheiterte
make: ** [LINUX] Fehler 2
```

so, also "make install" did not work after this compilation. 
Hope you can help me, before i am throwing this stick out of the Window.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it working in Ubuntu 18.04 with linux kernel 4.13.0-25-generic

How? [cperilla fork](https://github.com/cperilla/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916)

`$ git clone https://github.com/cperilla/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
$ cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat
(reboot, should not be necessary but I did it)`

Then I did `sudo iwlist ra0 scan` to get information on the networks

Having the information on the open network I wanted I did:

`sudo iwconfig ra0 mode Managed ap XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX channel 1 enc off key off
sudo iwpriv ra0 set SSID="<ssid>"
sudo dhclient ra0 -v`

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with you and resolved that and put all solution on GitHub, include, code for driver modified for Ubuntu 16.10.

https://github.com/Hygens/mt7610u_ubuntu_1610

> #### How to use
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/src
> cd ~/src
> git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
> make
> sudo make install
> sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat
> sudo reboot
> ```
>
> Refer to： http://hprath.com/2014/06/cisco-linksys-ae6000-ac580-media-tek-mt7610u-mt7630u-mt7650u-linux-x64-driver-patch/ On this page you'll find also details about configuration in RT2870STA.dat.
>
> https://github.com/chenhaiq/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916 (TP-Link T2U)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! As this post currently stands, it's not exactly up to our site's standards (see our [answer] page for why). Please [edit] your answer to include instructions as to how to install your patch, as well as what changes you made to it (so that if you ever delete the project, the instructions here won't be useless).  Also, please read our [tour] to get a better idea of how our site works. See you around!